# jQuery selectors and .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Why are the objects returned by a selector (for example `$("div")`) different from the objects you get by looping through the result of the selector with the `.each()` function?  I do not think I understand the exact semantics of either function.  Could someone clarify why they are different?  In particular if I form an array manually, why can I not call the same methods on objects of that array?

For example printing the values in the array for the two cases yields different results

```
array = $("div")
```

and

```
array = [];
$.each($("div"), function(index, value) {
    array.push(value);
});
```

---

#### Note

Turns out that they are in fact the same.  The difference was being cause for some reason because of the browser cache.  Cleaning up the cache made this work

Comment: The first example returns a jQuery collection, the second builds an array of jQuery collections. Arrays don't have jQuery methods.

Comment: How can I know when to wrap the result around a `$()` call and when to just use the jquery methods straight up?

Comment: @Juhana I was not trying to use the jquery methods on the array but rather on the elements in the array, for example on `array[0]`

Comment: Same logic here: DOM-Nodes also don't have the methods, that jQuery provides. That's the reason to use jQuery.

Comment: I'm wondering, because for your reputation, you don't seem to know much about types and classes. And that a method is only available on the instances of that particular type, ... and all the other stuff, down this road

Comment: @Thomas  I don't understand what makes you say so.  I am not very comfortable with dynamically typed languages as of yet and I also don't understand what exactly I asked that makes you feel like I don't understand types and classes.  The type that is returned by the `$("div")` call is a `jQuery` collection.  Then how can I execute a `.attr("id")` function on a collection?  And then if I loop through the collection and access the individual objects, why can I then not call the same method?  It would seem that it makes more sense to call that on an individual object rather than on a collection

Comment: @Curious : I'm not sure exactly what it is you're asking. Does my answer help you in any way? If not, can you explain why it's not helpful?

Comment: @JohnSlegers It does!  I was thinking myself into a circle.  I think its rather hard for me to understand something when I have been coding for the past 10 hours.

Comment: @Curious : Let me know if there's anything that still not clear to you with respect to this particular issue. Anyway, to prevent this question from getting more downvotes, i'd recommend being a bit more specific / detailed on what exactly you're struggling with. I had to kinda guesstimate what you were asking, and I think this lack of clarity may be the reason why some people are downvoting your question.

Comment: @JohnSlegers I understand!  I usually resist the urge to ask questions like this unless I am perfectly clear about what I am asking.  There was some sort of weird behavior in my browser due to the cache.  As soon as I cleared it things started working as I expected.   I did not know this could be an issue with web apps..

Comment: @Curious : I've been building websites for slightly more then 15 years now. If there's one constant in my experience as a web developer, it's the fact that no single browser will ever ever cease to amaze you with respect to un-intuitive behavior ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111331/discussion-between-john-slegers-and-curious).

Comment: @Downvoters Now that I edited my question could I get my rep back haha

Comment: @JohnSlegers I didn't notice!  I replied there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `function`, you can call `this` to reference to the element that function applies to!

You can wrap `$()` around `this` (`$(this)`) if you feel more comfortable working with jQuery objects.

The `index` parameter of your `function` corresponds with the position of the element in the list of selected elements.

The `value` parameter of your `function` corresponds with the element, which basically means that `this` and `value` have the same value.

---

#### Demo

```js
var data = [];
$.each($("div"), function(index, value) {
    data.push({
        'index' : index,
        'this' : $(this).attr("id"),
        'value' : $(value).attr("id")
    });
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2) + '<pre>';
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="test1">
  <div id="test2">
     Hello
  </div>
</div>
<div id="test3">
     World
</div>
<div id="test4">
    <div id="test5">
    </div>
    <div id="test6">
        <div id="test7">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```